# May accounts use ed25519

Tags: cryptography, key

Is it possible to use ed25519 for account key pairs on a substrate based blockchain instead of the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's totally possible.

This is how moonbeam did to use ECDSA.

https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/580a3ef92858f5e667176e8156efcd9e2f04d65a/primitives/account/src/lib.rs#L100

https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/580a3ef92858f5e667176e8156efcd9e2f04d65a/core-primitives/src/lib.rs#L28-L32

Basically, you just need to define the `Ed25519Signature` and implement those traits. And let the `<<Ed25519Signature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;` as your `AccountId`.